# Always keep admin UI in the same language when translating content

Tags: i18n-l10n, 9

I have set up a page with two languages (English, German). I have two users, one should get the German backend and the other user only understands English, he should get the English backend.
The frontend should be able to switch between the languages and the backend should always remain the same in the language.
I have also set up a language switch for the website and I use the AdminToolbar.
I also tried the following, but unfortunately it didn't help:

[Always keep admin UI in English when translating content](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224988/always-keep-admin-ui-i..).

At the moment I'm rather confused with the languages. The backend always jumps with the language and the menus can no longer be easily adapted with their translation.
I now strongly suspect that this is due to the "recognition and selection" function and the order of the recognition methods. But so far I haven't found an optimal order for the recognition methods myself.
So first it should show the language for the backend correctly and then control the frontend via the paths "de" and "en".

But I would be very grateful if you could help me. Oh, I use the latest Drupal 9 and use the Drupal Core standard modules for the translations.
So I would be grateful for any tips! I've already done some research, but haven't found the right solution yet.

Thanks and greetings

Bavra

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "one should get the German backend and the other user only understands English, he should get the English backend. The frontend should be able to switch between the languages and the backend should always remain the same in the language"  What is the actual requirement here?  Should both users get the backend in the same language (which language?), or should each user get the backend in a different language?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I have admin language English and frontend language another?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/195213/how-can-i-have-admin-language-english-and-frontend-language-another)

Answer (score 1):

Enable **Account administration pages** in language detection (don't change the priorities, the setup out-of-the-box is optimal). This adds a second language selector for admin pages to the user profile. Then every user with admin privileges can select their preferred language for the admin UI:

[image]

To translate then content in different languages while keeping the configured admin language enable *Customize Content language detection to differ from Interface text language detection settings* and enable the **URL** detection method in this section.

Whether this works with specific modules is a different problem and should be solved in the modules issue queue.